# How do I get the innerHTML of the selected Selenium WebElement using javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need to get the text enclosed in the returned span elements.

```
  driver.findElements(By.className("lvHighlightSubjectClass")).then(async (subjects) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const subject = subjects[i];
        if (subject) {
          console.log(await subject.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
        }
      }
  });
```

I seem to be getting a Promise back from each console.log call.  How can I access the attributes of the WebElements returned by findElements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just "await" the promise:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("lvHighlightSubjectClass")).then(async (subjects) => {
  for(let subject of subjects) {
    console.log(await subject.getInnerHtml())
  }
});
```

Comment: getInnerHTML() does not appear to be an available method on the element. is there a difference in span vs some other tag?

Comment: found solution. see edit in questions. thanks for the help!